# delete node from xml file throws me an object reference error

Tags: vb.net

I have an XML file that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<playlist>
     <name>My Playlist</name>
     <song>
         <name>Song Name Here</name>
         <path>Path to song here</path>
         <note>Song notes here</note>
         <artist>Song artist here</artist>
         <type>Song type here</type>
     </song>
     <song>
         <name>Song Name Here</name>
         <path>Path to song here</path>
         <note>Song notes here</note>
         <artist>Song artist here</artist>
         <type>Song type here</type>
     </song>
</playlist>
```

I am trying to delete the song node from the xml file but i can't figure out the cause of the error I'm getting. I'm still learning visual basics.

Error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

This is my code

```
    Private Sub MsItemRemoveClick(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles msItemRemove.Click

        If lvwPlaylist.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

            Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument

            xmlDoc.Load(_playlistpath & lblPlaylistName.Text & ".xml")

            Dim songs As XmlElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("song")

            For Each item As ListViewItem In lvwPlaylist.SelectedItems

                For Each node As XmlElement In songs

                    If node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText = item.SubItems(0).Text Then

                        MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText) '<------ this is where the error pops up on 'node.ParentNode.RemoveAll()

                    End If

                Next

                item.Remove()

            Next

            xmlDoc.Save(_playlistpath & lblPlaylistName.Text & ".xml")

        End If

    End Sub
```

My efforts are to loop through all selected listview items and if the name of the song matches the name of the song in the `songs node` then delete the parent node of `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripped out the ListView for clarity....

For this XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<playlist>
     <name>My Playlist</name>
     <song>
         <name>Alpha song</name>
         <path>Path to song here</path>
         <note>Song notes here</note>
         <artist>Song artist here</artist>
         <type>Song type here</type>
     </song>
     <song>
         <name>Beta song</name>
         <path>Path to song here</path>
         <note>Song notes here</note>
         <artist>Song artist here</artist>
         <type>Song type here</type>
     </song>
     <song>
         <name>Charlie song</name>
         <path>Path to song here</path>
         <note>Song notes here</note>
         <artist>Song artist here</artist>
         <type>Song type here</type>
     </song>
     <song>
         <name>Delta song</name>
         <path>Path to song here</path>
         <note>Song notes here</note>
         <artist>Song artist here</artist>
         <type>Song type here</type>
     </song>
</playlist>
```

saved on disk as C:\Junk\Junk1.xml, this code will find and remove the two middle nodes...

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
  Dim strFilenameIn As String = "C:\Junk\Junk1.xml"
  Dim strFilenameOut As String = "C:\Junk\Junk2.xml"

  Dim lstNames As New List(Of String)
  lstNames.Add("Beta song")
  lstNames.Add("Charlie song")

  Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
  xmlDoc.Load(strFilenameIn)
  For Each strSongName As String In lstNames
    Dim xnl As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/playlist/song/name")
    For i As Integer = xnl.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
      Dim xnd As XmlNode = xnl(i)
      If xnd.FirstChild.Value = strSongName Then 'match'
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(xnd.ParentNode)
      End If
    Next
  Next strSongName
  xmlDoc.Save(strFilenameOut)
  MsgBox("Finished")
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! I'm going to study this code and see what I can learn from it when making other functions err subs.